# Mellin Transform $M[\log(x)f(x)] = \frac{d}{ds}F(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mellin-transform

My solutions say:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}F(s) = \frac{\mathrm {d}}{\mathrm {d}s}\int_0^\infty \! x^{s-1}f(x) \, \mathrm {d}x = \int_0^\infty \! \log(x)x^{s-1}f(x)\,\mathrm {d}x = M\left[(\log(x))f(x)\right]
$$

I cant see how $$
\frac{\mathrm {d}}{\mathrm {d}s}\int_0^\infty \! x^{s-1}f(x) \, \mathrm {d}x = \int_0^\infty \! \log(x)x^{s-1}f(x)\, \mathrm {d}x
$$

Comment: Assuming good enough convergence for the integral, you can insert the differential operator inside the integral and use the standard fact that the derivative (in $s$) of $a^{s-1}$ is $(\log a)a^{s-1}$ for any fixed positive $a$, with $x=a$ here

Comment: thanks, i appreciate it mate!!

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar - Conrad is speaking to "Leibniz's Integral Rule"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule